# Display mongoDB data in a table with most recent date at the top of list in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I have built an application using MERN stack that displays a table of orders.

Currently, I am displaying my orders in a table with the most recent order at the bottom. How do I flip this round, so that the most recent order is displayed at the top? I would also like to only display orders from today's date.

I am using the following code to fetch my orders:

```
export const fetchOrders = () => (dispatch) => {
  fetch("/api/orders")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_ORDERS, payload: data });
    });
};
```

and I am displaying the results of this using the following code:

```
class Orders extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchOrders();
  }

  render() {
    const { orders } = this.props;
    console.log(orders);

    return !orders ? (
      <div>No Orders</div>
    ) : (
      <div className="orders" key={orders._id}>
        <h2>Orders</h2>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>DATE</th>
              <th>NAME</th>
              <th>DEPARTMENT</th>
              <th>ADDITIONAL INFO</th>
              <th>ITEMS</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {orders.map((order) => (
              <tr>
                <td>{order._id}</td>
                <td>{order.createdAt}</td>
                <td>{order.name}</td>
                <td>{order.department}</td>
                <td>{order.additionalInfo}</td>
                <td>
                  {order.cartItems.map((item) => (
                    <div>
                      {item.count} {" x "} {item.title}
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default connect(
  (state) => ({
    orders: state.order.orders,
  }),
  {
    fetchOrders,
  }
)(Orders);
```

My response data from my console.log on orders is:
[image]

Comment: Can you share what format `createdAt` is in the data?

Comment: I've used timestamps: true in my Schema

Comment: Can you update your question with the response data here

Comment: I've updated my question with the response data from a console log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the data before dispatching the result:

```
export const fetchOrders = () => (dispatch) => {
  fetch("/api/orders")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      const sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
        const dateAInMillis = (new Date(a.createdAt)).getTime();
        const dateBInMillis = (new Date(b.createdAt)).getTime();
        
        return dateBInMillis - dateAInMillis;
      })


      dispatch({ type: FETCH_ORDERS, payload: sortedData });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks Aadil, this is exactly what I was looking for! Do you know how to data further so that only orders from today are displayed?

Comment: Yeah you can filter before sorting with a current date

Comment: How would you do it?

Comment: Do you have future dates as well?

Comment: No, the application is for food orders so on the admin side, I'd like to just display orders from today's date to make things as easy to read as possible. Alternatively, I did think about creating a filter so the user can filter the dates instead?

Answer (score 0):

This really just comes down to your query. It should look something like

```
const orders = await Orders.find({
  ...,
  createdAt: {
    $gte: moment().tz(<the users timezone>).startOf('day')
  }
}, {
  sort: { createdAt: -1 }
})
```